How to add power BI with flutter android app
I create a flutter android app and for data analytics and I want to show my power BI analysis In to our flutter android app how I can add power BI ?
I create a flutter android app and for data analytics and I want to show my power BI analysis In to our flutter android app how I can add power BI ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
